# Problem redirecting output of find to a file

Tags: unix, find, pipe

I am trying to put the result of a find command to a text file on a unix bash shell

Using:

```
find ~/* -name "*.txt" -print > list_of_txt_files.list
```

However the list_of_txt_files.list stays empty and I have to kill the find to have it return the command prompt. I do have many txt files in my home directory

Alternatively How do I save the result of a find command to a text file from the commandline. I thought that this should work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first thing I would do is use single quotes (some shells will expand the wildcards, though I don't think `bash` does, at least by default), and the first argument to `find` is a *directory*, not a list of files:

```
find ~ -name '*.txt' -print > list_of_txt_files.list
```

Beyond that, it may just be taking a long time, though I can't imagine anyone having *that* many text files (you say you have a lot but it would have to be pretty massive to slow down `find`). Try it first without the redirection and see what it outputs:

```
find ~ -name '*.txt' -print
```

Comment: My machine was just running very slow when I tried this command with and without redirecting  output to file. The slow machine caused the redirected output to be a lot slower- i.e after a few minutes file was still zero bytes whereas without the output redirection, the *.txt files were listed immediately. Now that my machine has more resources both ways seem as fast.

Answer (score 8):

You can redirect output to a  file and console together by using tee.

```
find ~ -name '*.txt' -print | tee result.log
```

This will redirect output to console and to a file and hence you don't have to guess whether if command is actually executing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec echo {} \\; > zips.out
```

Comment: This worked, but only with a single backslash before the semi-colon, using `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git`